# SSL question java web application

Tags: java, ssl

I configure my web application to use SSL using my own self signed certificate. Everything is working fine but here my whole site is https now as i used :-

```
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
```

However, i only want my login page to use SSL and not complete site. What changes do i need to make in my application?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check out my answer to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840211/setup-ssl-for-form-login-only-on-tomcat-webapp/1840398#1840398

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- let all links be regular
- let the link to the login page be `https://...`
- on the login page make sure all links are `http://`

For example:

```
<a href="https://<%= request.getServerName() %>/login.jsp">
```

(you many need to also include `request.getServletContext().getContextPath()` as well)

Comment: Hi Bozho! You mean i should hardcode everything like http://localhost/common/abc.jsf? rather than /common/abc.jsf?

Comment: not hardcode. Use it dynamically, via `request` - it holds all the data - the server, the url, the context

Comment: Hi Bozho, the solution you posted is not working. When i change from https to http the login fails and i get this exception as i am using jdbcRealm :- INFO: JACC Policy Provider: Failed Permission Check, context(Blogger/Blogger)- permission((javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission /Login/index.jsf GET))

Comment: probably the sessionid is changing that's why this problem is coming

Comment: I've implemented https login in exactly the same way. So perhaps there is something other than this.

Comment: Hi Bozho, see this link, i have done it this way :-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914751/why-does-this-redirect-not-work-java-ssl

Comment: the first time i do login i get the above exception and the 2nd time i do login :p i go inside members area but with https instead of http. Please help me :(

Comment: Shall i post my whole web.xml here?

Comment: Hi Bozho, i would to add that if i keep simple <a> on my login page and click there then http works fine. But when i am programmatically redirecting using http it doesn't work.